# OpenSSL 1.0.x possible in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Is there a way to get an OpenSSL 1.0.x package in Ubuntu 11.04, without building from source ?

`apt-get update/upgrade` only brings one to 0.9.8g

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 is in the final beta stage and Ubuntu 12.04.1 is the new LTS release. 11.04 is basically unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no officially supported way to get it in natty. You might be able to find someone somewhere who's packaged it up, but if you want to use trusted sources you're not going to find it on a version lower than  11.10, and if you want the latest version of openssl you're going to want to go to 12.04